# ASP.NET MVC getting cookie name of a specific domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, cookies

We will have have only dynamic named cookie on the domain. how can i get the name of the cookie.

After getting the name i have to Add a list to the cookie, which will have other values as well already added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at the [Request.Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.cookies.aspx) property which represents a collection of all cookies sent by the client browser. You may loop through the cookies and look for the one you are interested in by using the [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.name.aspx) property. Once you find it you may modify it's [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.value.aspx) property. As an alternative you could manipulate the [Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.values.aspx) property.